# How to print variable

Tags: java, variables, initialization

In my code I need to print out the `tax` variable. It's not working and I think I know why I just don't know how to do it. I need to initialize the variable `tax` but I don't know how to in a main class. Here is my code.

```
   System.out.println("Enter your income!");
   double income = scan.nextDouble();

   if (income < 50000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100;
   }
   else if (income < 75000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100 * 2;
   }
   else if (income < 100000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100 * 3;
   }
   else if (income < 250000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100 * 4;
   }
   else if (income < 500000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100 * 5;
   }
   else if (income > 500000)
   {
       double tax = income / 100 * 6;
   }
```

Comment: Why not taged java???

Comment: `tax` will exist only in the block it is declared (the `if` statement). You will have to declare it outside your `if` and just assign it the proper value in the `if`.

Comment: You need to define the variable outside of if scoop

Comment: Put the following statements before the if and else

Comment: double tax = 0;

Comment: And do not forget to remoce all the definitions for tax variable inside the if

Comment: I fixed it thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
double tax = 0.0;
```

This line should be above the rest of your code. Then in your if statements remove the declarations of tax and instead just assign your expressions to tax:

```
tax = income / 100 * some number;
```

What is happening in your code right now is that there is a different tax variable for each else if statement you have, and because of the behavior of scope in java the program can only see the tax variable inside the else if that it is declared in. For example:

```
if(condition){
  double tax = number;
}
else if(condition){
  double tax = number;
}
else{
   double tax = number;
}
```

This code block is similar to what you have. The tax variables in this code block can only be used inside their respective code blocks. Only between the curly braces does each tax variable exist. Once you leave the curly braces that variable no longer exists. It is deleted by java. Then when you reach the next set of curly braces and declare tax anew it is an entirely different variable as compared to this code

```
function(){
    double tax = 0.0;
    if(condition){
       tax = number;
    }
    else if(condition){
       tax = number;
    }
    else{
       tax = number;
     }
  }
```

tax is the same variable throughout the if statements here because it exists between the curly braces of the function and not only between the curly braces of an if statement because it was declared outside the if statements.